# Antivirus to fix the malware infected files (not to delete them)?

Tags: server, malware

My server got hit with malware. Now I downloaded full back up. When I scan it for a virus, my anti-virus deletes the infected files but I need them to be fixed and upload back. Please suggest me free anti-virus to fix the virus.

PS: There are 7000 infected files so there is no chance of fixing them one by one manually.

Comment: Look here for why once infected, your only sane choice is a full reformat: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231